# What does an asterisk argument in an __init__ method mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code I'm using has a class definition, and the `__init__` method contains a `*` as an argument.  As a simple example,

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar
```

This is working code in Python 3.6 .  What does the `*` argument do?